# Como colocar música em console application com C#?

Tags: c#, .net, áudio

Estou criando um jogo em C# (console application) e preciso colocar um fundo musical, como faço?

Answer (score 5):

Conforme exemplo da documentação da [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) pode-se usar algo como:

Importa:

```
using System.Media;
```

E use assim:

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = Environment.CurrentLocation + "typewriter.wav";
```

No caso você só precisa setar a localização do audio em `SoundLocation` e depois executar `.Play` (executa de forma assincrona, para carregar de forma sincrona, que pode travar o app dependendo do caso, use `PlaySync`):

```
try {
    player.Play();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //Somente um exemplo exibir erros em caso de falha, pode modificar como desejar
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não dá detalhes, mas o básico seria mais ou menos isso:

```
var player = new SoundPlayer("NomeDoArquivo.wav");
player.Play();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/PlaySound.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Comment: desde já sou grato meu amigo, estou programando a bem pouco tempo.

Comment: @WilsonDayvis talvez pudesse marcar uma resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro inclua o `using System.Media;` no começo do código, depois disso, para diferenciar das outras respostas, você pode incluir uma Resource de um som (vá em Project > NomeDoProjeto Properties... > Resources > clique para criar um arquivo de Resources > procure o canto de adicionar um áudio) e depois colocar pro SoundPlayer toca-lo.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.SimpleSound);
    soundPlayer.Play(); // Para começar o som normalmente.
    soundPlayer.PlayLooping(); // Para começar o som e ficar repetindo.
    soundPlayer.PlaySync(); // Para começar o som e só ir para a próxima linha quando parar de tocar.
}
```

Comment: Esse texto me é familiar, você poderia citar a fonte de onde pegou isso? Não copie informações de onde você não sabe se pode copiar, e se puder copiar, sempre cite a fonte. Isso está sendo debatido aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5430/101